# How to store and view the file in Iphone using IOS Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am new to swift and trying to save the file on iphone and view them using file manager app present in app store. but every time the path looks like its getting stored in my mac machine. below is code which i have written for storing a simple text file

```
 func saveImageDocumentDirectory(){
        let str = "Super long string here"
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("output.txt")

        do {
            try str.write(to: filename, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            print(filename.path)
        } catch {
            // failed to write file – bad permissions, bad filename, missing permissions, or more likely it can't be converted to the encoding
        }

    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
```

but path at which file is getting stored is printed as below

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/ACBC0B24-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-BDAA4901EA41/Documents/output.txt
```

Comment: That path looks correct.  Apps from the app store will not be able to read your app's files due to sandboxing.

Comment: which app should i use to view the file ? i m using two app from app store 1. file manager and other is file explorer

Comment: None. You can download the application container using the devices window in Xcode. iOS apps are sandboxed;  they cannot read outside of their own data, so another app on your device can’t read your app’s data.

Comment: we cant see the directory we are creating thats so sad

Comment: “You” (your app) can see it. No one else can.  This is a really important and fundamental piece of iOS security.

Comment: how to view it? Can i view directory via Xcode ?

Comment: Yes, as I said above, from the devices window you can download the application container to your Mac, then ctrl-click on the file and select “show contents” to look inside the container file.

Comment: but my application container is showing empty